# Writing long NoteText

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA in Excel to write a comment. If the comment is short enough it works fine, however if it becomes too long it doesn't write a comment at all any more. In the following example it works if I cut the comment after the last ellipses. Is there any solution for that problem?

```
Sub longComment()
Cells(1, 3).NoteText Text:="Hello, I am a very long comment. Why can't I be written as a comment? It seems there is something very strange happening! Does anyone know what's wrong with me? How can I avoid this problem? See what happens when I add another line ... and another one ... and one more still!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using the `NoteText` method, you can directly use the comment object, whose `Text` method doesn't have that annoying 255 character limit:

```
Sub test()
    If Range("A1").Comment Is Nothing Then Range("A1").AddComment
    Range("A1").Comment.Text String(10000, "*")
End Sub
```

Comment: You have really spoiled my fun! :)

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have managed to get:

```
Sub allWeNeedIsLongComment()

    Dim commentToBeAdded    As String
    Dim commentSigns        As Long
    Dim cnt                 As Long
    Dim addToFixTheLoop     As Long

    commentToBeAdded = "Here is FatBox Slim...." & vbCrLf & _
                       "1.  Push the tempo! Push the tempo!Push the tempo!" & vbCrLf & _
                       "2.  Push the tempo! Push the tempo!Push the tempo!" & vbCrLf & _
                       "3.  Push the tempo! Push the tempo!Push the tempo!" & vbCrLf & _
                       "4.  Push the tempo! Push the tempo!Push the tempo!" & vbCrLf & _
                       "5.  Push the tempo! Push the tempo!Push the tempo!" & vbCrLf & _
                       "6.  Push the tempo! Push the tempo!Push the tempo!" & vbCrLf & _
                       "7.  Push the tempo! Push the tempo!Push the tempo!" & vbCrLf & _
                       "8.  Push the tempo! Push the tempo!Push the tempo!" & vbCrLf & _
                       "9.  Push the tempo! Push the tempo!Push the tempo!" & vbCrLf & _
                       "10. Push the tempo! Push the tempo!Push the tempo!" & vbCrLf & _
                       "Oh push the tempo!"

    commentSigns = Len(commentToBeAdded)
    If Not Range("C3").Comment Is Nothing Then Range("C3").Comment.Delete
    addToFixTheLoop = commentSigns Mod 255 + 1

    For cnt = 1 To (commentSigns + addToFixTheLoop) Step 255
        If cnt = 1 Then
            Range("C3").NoteText Text:=Mid(commentToBeAdded, cnt, 255)
        Else
            Range("C3").NoteText Text:=Mid(commentToBeAdded, cnt, 255), Start:=cnt

        End If
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image]

Or you can simply use the `.Comment` and not care about the loops and etc.

Answer (score 2):

To add a note that contains more than 255 characters, use this method once to specify the first 255 characters, and then use it again to append the remainder of the note (no more than 255 characters at a time).

[NoteText Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/range-notetext-method-excel?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144166)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue)